# How do I change the gamemode in minecraft PE 0.10.0?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I was somewhere else, someone else said to change the chunks.dat file onto another world. However, my the world has 2 files: db and level.dat file. Anyone know how to get the chunks.dat file? Or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Just go into I file, copy the level.dat file of a creative map and paste it into a survival map and bam. that or you can do the same on I explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Bro if you paste level.dat into the opposite world, it works as the other for eg. Survival level.dat -> Creative file, you will have all blocks, can't craft and can die when zombies and that touch you.